# Query + Importrange function doesn't work with Contains parameter ( QUERY : PARSE_ERROR)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import a set of columns from a sheet to another with a "filter" parameter which exclude some value.

My formula look like this :

`=Query(importrange("URL";"sheet name!a2:be");"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE Col8 NOT CONTAINS 'alc'")`

However I came across with this error :

> #VALEUR! Unable to parse query string for parameter 2 of function QUERY : PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "Col8 "" at line 1, column 86.
> Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ... .

I don't know why it doesn't work, CONTAINS is a valid parameter and even after reading documentation at 
[Google Visualization API query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) i found no error in my syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:**

The correct syntax is `NOT Col8 CONTAINS` and not `Col8 NOT CONTAINS`.

**Solutions:**

`=Query(importrange("URL";"sheet name!a2:be");"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE NOT Col8 CONTAINS 'alc'")`

Another approach would be to use `Col8 <> 'alc'`:

`=Query(importrange("URL";"sheet name!a2:be");"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE Col8 <> 'alc'")`

Comment: Thank you it works, now how can i add more parameters using the same function ? I need to filter my import using more excluding terms. Some people suggest using MATCHES function instead, however even if i add .* before and after every terms it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JawadBounaâs thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Could you please post a new question regarding that and me and other developers will be able to help you. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: i partially figured it out, take a look at my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169244/google-sheet-query-matches-function-doesnt-exclude-strings

Answer (score 0):

=Query(importrange("URL";"sheet name!a2:be");"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE NOT Col8 CONTAINS 'alc'")

Comment: duplicate answer