# Google sheet QUERY + MATCHES function doesn't exclude strings

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import rows from a sheet that exclude certains character. I did it first using the CONTAINS function but i didn't find a way to do it with multiple parameters. So i did it using the MATCHES function :

`=Query(importrange("URL";"Sheet!a:be");"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE NOT Col8 MATCHES '.*alc.*|.*vin.*|.*alcool.*'")`

however there is still rows where those strings appear in Col8, i don't know why ?

How could i do it in order to filter my import excluding those strings no matter what ?

Comment: Please share an example sheet where this issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

In case the rows are not filtered out because of `MATCHES` is case sensitive (it is, and one cannot use flags in `QUERY`'s regex), you can use `FILTER` instead:

```
=FILTER(
  QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "Sheet!A:BE");
    "SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49"
  );
  NOT(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "Sheet!H:H"); "(?i)alc|vin|alcool"))
)
```

Comment: Thank you it works properly that way, however it import all the columns of my sheet while i only need the columns i defined in my first formula. Is it possible to define those same columns using FILTER function ? As is it not a QUERY formula anymore what will be the equivalent of SELECT WHERE ?

Comment: I also would like to know why the MATCHES function is case sensitive ? Why it doesn't filter properly ?

Comment: @JawadBounaâs sorry I totally forgot about the columns. Fixed it (added your SELECT). MATCHES uses regular expressions which are case sensitive by default, but you can use a flag (putting `(?i)` in regex) to make it case insensitive. But flags are not supported in `QUERY`. Why that is so - that's the question for Google Sheets developers, I have no idea.