# Import function using QUERY + REGEXMATCH doesn't work with excluding & select parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import a sheet by 2 different filter function. The first one need to include every row where the value of column 14 is equal to 1, the second one need to exclude rows where column H contains one of those strings "alc" "alcool" "vin". I've seen it in previous questions here [google-sheet-query-matches-function-doesnt-exclude-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169244/google-sheet-query-matches-function-doesnt-exclude-strings). However when i try to add the first filter into my previous formula it doesn't work, here is my formula :

```
=FILTER(
  QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "Sheet!A:BE");
    "SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col26, Col8, Col30, Col40, Col41, Col44, Col45, Col49 WHERE Col14 = "1""
  );
  NOT(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "Sheet!H:H"); "(?i)alc|vin|alcool"))
)
```

I try both using and not using `""` as the values of my column are numbers but none of them work

Comment: share a copy of your sheets

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RV1-mxrd4wjVBw8hNu1yQAOZvlaO0jD5Ar5AArg-7QE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RV1-mxrd4wjVBw8hNu1yQAOZvlaO0jD5Ar5AArg-7QE";
 "wc-product-export-27-11-2020-1606486738987!A:BE");
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col26,Col8,Col30,Col40,Col41,Col44,Col45,Col49 
  where Col14 = 1"); 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RV1-mxrd4wjVBw8hNu1yQAOZvlaO0jD5Ar5AArg-7QE";
 "wc-product-export-27-11-2020-1606486738987!A:BE");
 "select Col8 
  where Col14 = 1"); "(?i)alcool|vin|alc")))
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RV1-mxrd4wjVBw8hNu1yQAOZvlaO0jD5Ar5AArg-7QE";
 "wc-product-export-27-11-2020-1606486738987!A:BE");
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col26,Col8,Col30,Col40,Col41,Col44,Col45,Col49 
  where Col14 = 1
    and not lower(Col8) contains "&JOIN(" and not lower(Col8) contains "; "'"&SPLIT(
 "alcool|vin|alc"; "|")&"'")))
```

Comment: No it doesn't work properly, as explained in my previous question that i've linked MATCHES function is "case sensitive" --> MATCHES uses regular expressions which are case sensitive by default, but you can use a flag (putting (?i) in regex) to make it case insensitive. But flags are not supported in QUERY. @player0

Comment: So in order to filter it properly i have to use REGEX and flags, however i don't know how add a second filter parameter using this. @player0